# Why does the WHO's definition of respiratory droplets encompass such small diameters?

Tags: covid-19, respiratory-system, who-world-health-org, airborne-transmission

I frequently hear the World Health Organization (WHO) identify diameters of 5-10 μm as the size cutoff between "respiratory dropletes" and "droplet nuclei". For example, in a [recent statement](https://www.who.int/news-room/commentaries/detail/modes-of-transmission-of-virus-causing-covid-19-implications-for-ipc-precaution-recommendations) they say:

> Respiratory infections can be transmitted through droplets of different sizes: when the droplet particles are >5-10 μm in diameter they are referred to as respiratory droplets, and when then are <5μm in diameter, they are referred to as droplet nuclei.

They go on to imply that this distinction is made because:

> Droplet transmission occurs when a person is in in close contact (within 1 m) with someone who has respiratory symptoms (e.g., coughing or sneezing) and is therefore at risk of having his/her mucosae (mouth and nose) or conjunctiva (eyes) exposed to potentially infective respiratory droplets... Airborne transmission is different from droplet transmission as it refers to the presence of microbes within droplet nuclei, which are generally considered to be particles <5μm in diameter, can remain in the air for long periods of time and be transmitted to others over distances greater than 1 m.

But the settling velocity of a sphere with the density of water and a diameter in the 5-10 μm range is on the order of several mm/sec at most. This means that a 10 μm sphere, for example, will [take over 8 minutes to fall 5 ft](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiEgeGtkvvrAhWilXIEHeWIAi0QFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cdc.gov%2Fniosh%2Ftopics%2Faerosols%2Fpdfs%2Faerosol_101.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1eHRyvt7T6eK5DhyizJOPy) (1.5 meters), which is more than ample time to travel over 1 meter horizontally. So why does the WHO link the transition between these two classes of aerosols with such a small diameter?

Comment: Guessing this is one of those places where an arbitrary cutoff is simply arbitrary.

Comment: Arbitrary cutoff and also just plain poor writing. I gather from other sources that the distinction is between nuclei which are <10 μm and can linger in the air far longer than droplets, which are >10 μm. Simple as that. The author(s) just didn't explain it well.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "link the transition".

Comment: This does not answer your question, however it does address the settling time of aerosols and is specifically related to Sars-CoV-2 , https://medium.com/edge-of-innovation/how-long-do-aerosol-particles-stay-airborne-7c660e089d9b

Comment: @BobE thanks for the helpful link. And by "link the transition" I was referring to the WHO stating that  "respiratory droplets" and "droplet nuclei" were larger and smaller than 10 μm, respectively.

Comment: @CareyGregory and BryanKrause – The article I linked does seem to have been written hastily but the 10 μm diameter is referenced in many places so I assume it is a relatively official stance taken by the WHO. The distinction between "respiratory droplets" and "droplet nuclei" seems to generally occur in discussions of how far an airborne contagion can travel. Since this is determined predominately by the size of the aerosol, it seems odd to arbitrarily reference a diameter that corresponds to particles that are still small enough to remain airborne for an extended period of time.